# AWS Neptune Gremlin query gives MemoryLimitExceededException

Tags: gremlin, memory-limit, amazon-neptune

We have 3.7M nodes and 11.2M relations in AWS Neptune. Here we need these nodes: `Organization`, `Member`, `Proposal`, `Vote` and relations:
`Member-[:IN]->Organization`, `Vote-[:BELONGS_TO]->Proposal`, `Vote-[:VOTED_BY]->Member`, `Member-[:IN]->Organization`.

The goal is to build the query which finds pairs of members in organization and count of proposals they voted with the same `vote.choice`. Here is the query:

```
g.V().has('Organization','id','${id}').as('d').
match(
 as('d').in('IN').hasLabel('Vote').as('v1').out('BELONGS_TO').hasLabel('Proposal').as('p'),
 as('d').in('IN').hasLabel('Vote').as('v2').out('BELONGS_TO').hasLabel('Proposal').as('p1').
  select('p1','p').where('p1',eq('p')
 ),
 as('v1').out('VOTED_BY').hasLabel('Member').as('m1'),
 as('v2').out('VOTED_BY').hasLabel('Member').as('m2').
  select('v1','v2').by('choice').where('v1',eq('v2'))).
  select('m1','m2').by('address').where('m1',lt('m2')).
   group().by(
    select('m1','m2')).by(select('p').count()
   ).
   order(local).by(values, desc).
   limit(local, 20)
```

The issue is that the query returns this error for Organizations with a lot of Members and Votes:

```
{"code":"MemoryLimitExceededException","detailedMessage":"Query cannot be completed due to memory limitations.","requestId":"e8f8a361-40c4-4db9-8da4-a618d0e20d92"}
```

Can the memory config be adjusted on AWS Neptune? Or should the query be optimized and what are ways to optimize it?

**UPDATE:**

The query without `match`:

```
g.V().has('Dao','organizationId','${id}').as('d').in('IN').hasLabel('Vote').as('v1').out('BELONGS_TO').hasLabel('Proposal').as('p'). 
 select('d').in('IN').hasLabel('Vote').as('v2').out('BELONGS_TO').hasLabel('Proposal').as('p1').where(eq('p')).select('v1').out('VOTED_BY').hasLabel('Member').as('m1'). 
 select('v2').out('VOTED_BY').hasLabel('Member').as('m2').where('v1',eq('v2')).by('choice').
 select('m1','m2').by('address').where('m1',lt('m2')).
   group().by( 
     select('m1','m2') 
   ).by(
     select('p').count()
   ).
 order(local).by(values, desc).
 limit(local,20)
```

Original Cypher query:

```
CALL {
    MATCH (o:Organization { id: '${id}' })<-[:IN]-(p:Proposal)
    RETURN COUNT(p) AS total_proposals_count
}
WITH total_proposals_count
MATCH (o:Organization { id: '${id}' })<-[:IN]-(v1:Vote)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(p:Proposal)
MATCH (o)<-[:IN]-(v2:Vote)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(p)
MATCH (v1)-[:VOTED_BY]->(m1:Member)
MATCH (v2)-[:VOTED_BY]->(m2:Member)
WHERE m1.address < m2.address AND v1.choice = v2.choice
RETURN [m1, m2] AS members, COUNT(p) AS voted_together, total_proposals_count
ORDER BY voted_together DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: It is seldom necessary to use the `match` step in Gremlin. It is a step that tends to yield poorly performing queries. Rewriting the query to just use `where` steps would be a good place to start.

Comment: I've updated the query to get rid of `match` but it's still slower than Cypher query. Any suggestions on how it can be optimized more?

Comment: If you are converting from Cypher to Gremlin, can you please add the original Cypher query to the question? The Gremlin can I am sure be further simplified.

Comment: Yes, I'm converting it from Cypher. Attaching it to the question.

Comment: What size instance are you running on?  Do you have a small set of test data you can share?

Comment: @bechbd We running on db.r5.large with 2 CPUs and 16GiB RAM. I can extract some subset of data but in what format can I share it?

Comment: If you have a small set of addV/addE statements that would probably be the easiest to share here.

Comment: Additionally, while I am taking a look at the query, you could use a larger instance size which will give you more memory for this query to complete.